# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager

Tags: java, wsdl2java

I'm currently working on Web Service in NetBean IDE.
I'm using `Apache HttpClient` to send `GET` request to some RESTful API.
The problem is, it works really well in junit test but when I compile it and delpoy to glassfish, it shows following error:

```
Info:   wsimport successful
Severe:   sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.init(Handshaker.java:282)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.<init>(Handshaker.java:242)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.<init>(ClientHandshaker.java:160)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1329)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:690)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:569)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
```

Here is my code to send `GET` request. What is the problem?

```
protected String getResponse(String url) throws IOException, ProviderNotAvailableException{
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            return result;
        } else {
            throw new ProviderNotAvailableException("Http entity is null.");
        }
}
```

My jdk version is 1.8 and NetBean version is 11.0. Again, it works well in junit test.

Comment: Problems may be at least one of the following:missing or different dependencies for test or a bug in the versione of server you are using in conjunction with the version of jdk you have. In any case it will be useful know what is the update of your jdk and the version ofyour glassfish.

Comment: @Renato I used upgrade version 221 and it's OK now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use JDK v1.8. Upgraded to 1.8u221 and problem solved.